# Flat Window when using C++/OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, window, flags

Thanks for the answers to my last question, they really helped.

I am following the Advanced C++/OpenGL Tutorials playlist, and before tutorial 19, eveything was working fine. But now, I have a flat window, that only has the window title.

[image: Flat Window]

I don't know the exact reason, and I tried debugging it, but I think it is something to do with the flags. 
Here is my solution folder:

[GraphicsTutorial.7z](http://www.mediafire.com/file/tjd00fab5qu2uxf/GraphicsTutorial.7z/file)

Maybe I made a small mistake that I can't find, because I redid the video, and I checked with it too.

I don't have any compiler or linker errors, so I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: You have to add the relevant code to the question. A linkt to a offsite resource is not sufficient. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: everybody tells me that, but i couldn't find the place that made the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the right way to post a question, but I'm feeling generous today.

**`Bengine/Window.cpp` line 33**:

```
_sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
     windowName.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
     screenWidth, _screenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
```

Notice how `screenWidth` is taken from the argument, but `_screenHeight` (with the underscore) is member variable of the `Window` class, which is never initialized.

Remove the underscore, or improve the design of this class so it actually adheres to the RAII principle.

Comment: oh thanks! That was really nice, it was very small indeed. Thought i wasn't going to get an answer.